# d3.js ordinal scale returns a wrong value

Tags: d3.js, coffeescript

Can someone explain to me what i'am doing wrong and why 'B' is not '50' and 'C' is getting '0'?

Example (Coffeescript)

```
scale = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(['A', 'B', 'C']).range([0,100])

console.log scale.domain()
console.log scale.range()

console.log scale('A')
console.log scale('B')
console.log scale('C')
```

Result

```
["A", "B", "C"]
[0, 100]
0
100
0
```

[example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b0vktgjq/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `range` here, you define a one-to-one mapping between the domain and range values. See [the docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#ordinal_range), specifically:

> "If there are fewer elements in the range than in the domain, the scale will recycle values from the start of the range."

That's what's happening in your example: `C` is being mapped to the same range value as `A`

In this case it looks like you should use `rangePoints` instead. This will give you a continuous interval, subdivided into *n* evenly-spaced points, where *n* is the number of (unique) values in the input domain. See:

```
scale = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(['A', 'B', 'C']).rangePoints([0,100])
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/b0vktgjq/1/